# CSS Layout (1 div - 4 imgs floating from the right)

Tags: css, layout, html, css-float

I'm working on css [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGnNW.png) where the first div should contain text, the div's width and height should be flexible according to content. On the right there should be 4 (in future maybe more) images with the same dimensions, at the best adaptable to the first div, but they have to be squares. For now I have just something like [this](http://snippets.etabled.com/css/layouts/1-4.html). Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

What about using floats? You would have two container `div`s one float right. The images could easily be held in a table since they are all the same size. If you know the width of the images ahead of time you could have the first div predefined to that width and height so that if the layout gets too small it won't break apart the images.

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="" /></td>
            <td><img src="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="" /></td>
            <td><img src="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <p>some text here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I generally stray from tables but for such a simple layout that is easily defined with tables I make a few exceptions. The equivalent in CSS would be a cross-browser nightmare and be significantly more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following HTML:

```
​<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="display">Some text</div>
    <div id="rightBar">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Along with the following CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline-block
}

#display {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#rightBar {
    width: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    float: left;
}

#rightBar div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WSZjA/)

Comment: Downside to this is cross-browser compatibility. IE7 and Firefox < 3 don't understand `inline-block`.

Comment: There is a quick and easy workaround though, see this article: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say quick and easy but that is definitely worth noting. My issue is it just seems like one hack on top of another.